# jquery ajax form.serialize() not working on Server and on local IIS

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have below code in Partial View ,Jquery and Controller .

I have used  $("form").serialize(); method and trying to Post Data to Controller in which I am

catching it in Model .

Code is working fine on Local when I run it with VS2010 but Code is not working on Server  for

around 100 Records when I am trying to send it to Controller Screen gets hang on for more than 30

min.Also not getting any error on server.

Can anyone let me know more about it.

1] Jquery Code

```
     $('#btnSave').click(function () {
    $("#dvAjax1").css('display', 'block');
    var assignCalculationsData = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax(
    { type: "POST",
        url: "SaveAssignedCalculations/Pricing",
        data: assignCalculationsData,
        success: function (data) {
            data = $.trim(data);
            if (data != "") {
                var $response = $(data);
                var hdValue = $response.find('#hdSaveStatus').val();

                if (hdValue == "2") {//enter mandatory
                    jAlert('Please enter mandatory data.');
                }
                else if (hdValue == "1") {

                    $("#dvBody").html("");
                    $("#dvBody").html(data);

                    jAlert('Calculations Saved Successfully');
                }
                else {//No Data ('0')
                    jAlert('Please enter mandatory data.');
                }
            }
            else {
                jAlert('Please assign calculation(s) before saving.');
            }
            $("#dvAjax1").css('display', 'none');
          }
       });
      });
      })
```

2] Controller Code

```
          public PartialViewResult SaveAssignedCalculations(List<AssignCalculationsDataModel> lstAssignCalculationsSourceDataModel, string fundType, string accountCode, string shareClassID)
           {
             //Some code
           }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `timeout` property and see if the server takes more time to process the request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "SaveAssignedCalculations/Pricing",
    type: "POST",        
    timeout: 10000,
});
```

Comment: But How I can quickly Post this Large data to Controller any alternative because this should done in at least in few seconds.

Comment: @VaibhavDeshmukh, It is very difficult to answer. It should not take more time in javascript. not sure about how much time it takes in server side

Comment: but still my screen gets hang for more than 30 min when there is Large amount of data I am trying to send

Comment: Any one having any other idea ?